# Weird bug: Cmd+Tab sticks in Mavericks

Tags: macos

I am experiencing an odd bug that I haven't seen anywhere else.

When I use Cmd+Tab, it seems to stick on whatever application it lands on when I release Tab. It should open that application, but instead the app switcher remains active.

Then, I can either hit Enter and it will open that app (like it should have when I released Tab), or I can press Tab once more and it will move to the next app then open that app.

This happen every single time, UNLESS I perform the keystroke VERY quickly.

I submitted a bug report to Apple a couple months ago, and (to no surprise) I haven't heard back.

This has happened since I upgraded to Mavericks on release day.

I have tried various third-party applications, but Apple has made it impossible now to relinquish the keystroke from the system.

I'm at my wit's end, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work in a new user account?

Comment: What's the radar and/or steps to reproduce the bug? You could enter things into http://openradar.appspot.com and we can help reproduce, narrow down, etc...

Comment: I can't reproduce it on another computer, and I don't see how open radar works. I just tried the guest account and everything works fine, but on my account it messes up every time

Comment: @avtraino -- I was curious on Radar as well; this seems to summarize: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2008/11/open-radar-using-social-networking-to-squash-apple-bugs/ (sorry, can't help with it or your bug!)

Comment: @dolan thanks for the info! 

I can't use Radar as I am not an Apple developer, and all I can post to OpenRadar is exactly what I have posted here. I can't reproduce the bug on another computer. 

Is there any way of knowing what specific set of files is used to govern the App Switcher, so that I might replace them with those from a fresh install?

Comment: As grgarside recommended, try with new user account on same computer. If works fine, do `diff homedir1 homdir2` or something similar to see how two home dirs differ.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in again! I created a new user account, and the App Switcher works fine. I used diff on the two home dirs, but it doesn't tell me anything that I can't see in Finder. Am I looking for anything specific? The App Switcher must be run by some code, I just can't seem to figure out where it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code for this is in the Dock process.

Comment: @0942v8653 YOU DID IT! Thank you so much! I hadn't thought of that as a possibility. I just deleted com.apple.dock.plist from /Users/avtraino/Library/Preferences/ and restarted.   I have no idea what the problem was, but now everything is fine!  Thanks all.

Comment: @0942v8653: How about posting the solution as an answer?

Comment: @TomBarron done :)

Comment: @0942v8653: +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab ⇥</kbd> app switcher lives in Dock.app, as many other things do, like the desktop background, menu bar, Spaces, Exposé, and most obviously the Dock. So to fix this the easiest way would be to simply clear the Dock preferences using this Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app) command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock
```

For anyone not familiar with the `defaults` command, it is used to set or remove preferences, most of the time hidden ones. This line simply uses the `defaults` command to `delete` the preferences associated with the bundle ID of `com.apple.dock`, which is just a unique identifier for `Dock.app`. If you want to be a little more technical and see if you can salvage your Dock's app order and Stacks, try running

```
defaults read com.apple.dock
```

and looking for anything suspicious or corrupted, and then use `defaults delete` on the offending key.